# Ruby on rails Bundle error possibly due to spree gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git-bash

After Adding into my Gemfile the spree gems from their documentation I came across this error when trying to `bundle install`:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "cocaine":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    cocaine (= 0.6.0)

  In Gemfile:
ckeditor (>= 4.2.4, ~> 4.2) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.4, which depends on
  cocaine x86-mingw32

spree (~> 3.4.4) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 3.4.4, which depends on
  spree_core (= 3.4.4) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 3.4.4, which depends on
    paperclip (~> 5.1.0) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5) x86-mingw32

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Then When I try to `Bundle Update` I get this:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink -
(fixtures/ashared/views_rails_3/users/phone_number.json.rabl,
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rabl- 
0.13.1/fixtures/ashared/views_rails_3/users/phone_number.xml.rabl)
An error occurred while installing rabl (0.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rabl -v '0.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.5'

# This just fixes everything?
gem 'actionpack', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.5'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11', '>= 3.11.3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.7'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.6'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.2'

# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.1'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# hiredis is not supported on windows
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# SEO & Meta Tags
gem 'meta-tags'

# Text editor for blog posts
gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.4'

# Framework for forms, (forms that require ckeditor especially).
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.1'

# Contact form email delivery
gem 'mail_form'

# Ecommerce solution
gem 'spree', '~> 3.4.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.3'
```

I have no idea why or how this is even happening due to the newly added spree gems. Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide!

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: I'm using Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working on windows it has to be [this](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/8065) issue, check it out for more details. It looks like this might help you:

> Search cmd, right click, (Run as administrator), gem install rabl -v '0.13.1', and you're done.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to apply this. Can you help me understand how to go about doing this?

Comment: I tried installing the gem and this happened: 
`$ gem install rabl -v '0.13.1'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink - (fixtures/ashared/views_rails_3/users/phone_number.json.rabl, C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rabl-0.13.1/fixtures/ashared/views_rails_3/users/phone_number.xml.rabl)`

Comment: @Jake You should run terminal as administrator first by right clicking on its icon.